Transition tables from longitudinal data in the long format using R
This question is about how to generate frequency transition tables from longitudinal data in the long format using R base functions or commonly used packages such as dplyr. Consider the longitudinal data
id <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4)
state <- c("C","A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A")
period <- rep(c("Start", "End"), 4)
df <- data.frame(id, state, period)
df

  id state period
1  1      C  Start
2  1      A    End
3  2      A  Start
4  2      A    End
5  3      B  Start
6  3      A    End
7  4      C  Start
8  4      A    End

and the expected output
    transition freq
1     A to A    1
2     A to B    0
3     A to C    0
4     B to B    0
5     B to A    1
6     B to C    0
7     C to C    0
8     C to A    2
9     C to B    0

I can generate the above output using the function statetable.msm in the msm package. However, I would like to know if this could be generated by base functions in R or other packages such as dplyr. Help is much appreciated!

Is it always 2 rows per ID?

@zx8754 it's possible to have many rows per ID, but this particular case its 2 rows per ID. Thanks!

"start A end B" same as "start B end A" ?

@zx8754 Not same.

If there are many rows per ID, how do you know which Start matches with which End?

@AllanCameron we can get to know that by the IDs. The original data has many rows (unbalanced) per ID, but I am interest in the first row (1st wave) and the last row (last wave).

@TRichard can we assume that you have filtered the data frame and labeled the start and end, as per your example? If so, my solution below will work. Otherwise, can you post an example of your actual starting point?

With tidyverse, using left_join on the crossing states
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

left_join(crossing(Start = df$state, End = df$state), 
          pivot_wider(df, names_from = period, values_from = state)) %>% 
  reframe(freq = id * 0 + n(), .by = c(Start, End)) %>% 
  distinct()

output
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  Start End    freq
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 A     A         1
2 A     B        NA
3 A     C        NA
4 B     A         1
5 B     B        NA
6 B     C        NA
7 C     A         2
8 C     B        NA
9 C     C        NA

or, to get the complete desired format
left_join(crossing(Start = df$state, End = df$state), 
          pivot_wider(df, names_from = period, values_from = state)) %>% 
  mutate(freq = id * 0 + n(),
         freq = replace(freq, is.na(freq), 0), .by = c(Start, End)) %>% 
  mutate(transition = purrr::map2_vec(Start, End, ~ paste(.x, "to", .y)), .before=1) %>%
  select(-c(Start, End, id)) %>% 
  distinct()
Joining with `by = join_by(Start, End)`
# A tibble: 9 × 2
  transition  freq
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 A to A         1
2 A to B         0
3 A to C         0
4 B to A         1
5 B to B         0
6 B to C         0
7 C to A         2
8 C to B         0
9 C to C         0


A solution entirely within base R could be something like:
do.call("c",
  split(df$state, df$id) |>
  lapply(paste, collapse = " to ")) |>
  factor(levels = sort(c(outer(unique(df$state), unique(df$state), 
                               FUN = paste, sep = " to ")))) |>
  table() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c("transition", "freq"))
#>   transition freq
#> 1     A to A    1
#> 2     A to B    0
#> 3     A to C    0
#> 4     B to A    1
#> 5     B to B    0
#> 6     B to C    0
#> 7     C to A    2
#> 8     C to B    0
#> 9     C to C    0


You can try
states <- sort(unique(df$state))
transform(
    aggregate(
        id ~ .,
        merge(
            expand.grid(state.Start = states, state.End = states),
            reshape(
                df,
                direction = "wide",
                idvar = "id",
                timevar = "period"
            ),
            all = TRUE
        ),
        list,
        na.action = na.pass
    ),
    freq = lengths(id) * !is.na(id)
)

gives
  state.Start state.End   id freq
1           A         A    2    1
2           B         A    3    1
3           C         A 1, 4    2
4           A         B   NA    0
5           B         B   NA    0
6           C         B   NA    0
7           A         C   NA    0
8           B         C   NA    0
9           C         C   NA    0


You could merge permutations with repetition to the first and last element (I interpreted that from your comment) of the state variable pasted together.
> data.frame(
+   Var1=RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(sort(unique(df$state)), 2, rep=TRUE, 
+                                  FUN=paste, collapse=' to ') |> do.call(what='rbind')
+ ) |> 
+   merge(
+     split(df$state, df$id) |> lapply(\(x) toString(x[c(1, length(x))])) |>
+       sub(', ', ' to ', x=_) |> table() |> as.data.frame(),
+     all=TRUE
+   ) |> 
+   transform(Freq=replace(Freq, is.na(Freq), 0)) |>  setNames(c('transition', 'freq'))
  transition freq
1     A to A    1
2     A to B    0
3     A to C    0
4     B to A    1
5     B to B    0
6     B to C    0
7     C to A    2
8     C to B    0
9     C to C    0


An alternative format of the data is to store in a length(id) x length(period) matrix:
rows = unique(df$id)
cols = unique(df$period)
mat = matrix(nrow = length(rows), ncol = length(cols), 
             dimnames = list(id = rows, period = cols))
mat[cbind(df$id, df$period)] = df$state
#mat
#   period
#id  Start End
#  1 "C"   "A"
#  2 "A"   "A"
#  3 "B"   "A"
#  4 "C"   "A"

And then, tabulate:
lvls = unique(df$state)
as.data.frame(table(factor(mat[, "Start"], lvls), 
                    factor(mat[, "End"], lvls)))
#  Var1 Var2 Freq
#1    C    C    0
#2    A    C    0
#3    B    C    0
#4    C    A    2
#5    A    A    1
#6    B    A    1
#7    C    B    0
#8    A    B    0
#9    B    B    0

and format as needed afterwards.

a (detailled) solution with data.table :)
Code:
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

# define the example
dt_example <- data.table(
  id = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4),
  state = c("C","A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "C", "A"),
  period = rep(c("Start", "End"), 4)
)

# define the target output structure
dt_target <- data.table( 
  Start.Point = c( rep("A",3), rep("B",3),rep("C",3) ), 
  End.Point = rep(c("A", "B", "C"),3) 
)
dt_target[, Path := str_c(Start.Point, " -> ", End.Point)]

# work the data
dt_agregate <- merge( 
  dt_example[period == "Start", .(id, Start.Point = state)], 
  dt_example[period == "End", .(id, End.Point = state)], 
  by = "id", 
  allow.cartesian = T
)
dt_agregate[, Path := str_c(Start.Point, " -> ", End.Point)]

# attach the aggreagation results
dt_target <- merge(
   dt_target[,.(Path)],
   dt_agregate[, .(freq = .N), .(Path)],
   by = "Path", 
   all = T
 )

# replace NA by 0
setnafill(dt_target, fill = 0, cols = 2)
dt_target

Output:
Key: <Path>
     Path  freq
   <char> <int>
1: A -> A     1
2: A -> B     0
3: A -> C     0
4: B -> A     1
5: B -> B     0
6: B -> C     0
7: C -> A     2
8: C -> B     0
9: C -> C     0

